# PHP access to shared folder on Mac

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, shared-directory

I have to build the function to scan all folders, subfolders, and files on directory. I am able to do that now if its my own mac directories.

```
$parent_link = '/Users/myusername/Downloads';
$directory = dirToArray($parent_link);
var_dum($directory);

function dirToArray($dir) { 

   $result = array(); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
            //var_dump($result[$value]);
         } 
         else 
         { 
             $result[] = $value; 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   return $result; 
}
```

However, How php access shared folder on Mac?

current situation :

I can access the shared folder on Mac using finder (with permission).

The folder is currently shared by mac server (LAN).

php is installed on my computer.

Comment: the problem is how can I use php to access shared folder on Mac. what should I change on $parent_link?

Comment: The guy has no idea how is the path of a shared folder on mac

Comment: @enapupe thanks for help to explain

Comment: @JakeGould please have a look at the changes

Comment: How are you mounting the remote directory?

Comment: Can't the finder tell you the path via "[Get Info](http://www.krisyu.org/static/blog/img/2013/06/path-mac.jpg)"?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie, I tried that already When I get Info it keeps on loading. waited for 10 mins still loading.

Comment: I think OS X mounts shared folders under `/Volumes`. I'd start by looking there

Comment: @Brad, I didn't mount it, it just showed up on shared because it is on Local Area Network.

Comment: @jmjap If you use it, it will be mounted.

Comment: @Phil, search /Volumes from terminal but its not showing the shared folder

Comment: @Brad, Yup it shows up but when I access it using php access denied. Anyway to put the username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the method of how I access the shared server. Instead of forcing it to access the shared folder by changing the path (which I'm still not able to figure it out), I am using php ftp. The working code is as follow :

```
$hostname = '192.168.X.X';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$conn_id = ftp_connect($hostname);
$login = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);
$parent_link = 'Document';
if (!$conn_id) {
    echo 'Wrong server!';
    exit;
} else if (!$login) {
    echo 'Wrong username/password!';
    exit;
} else {
    $directory = dirToArray($conn_id, $parent_link);
    var_dump($directory);
}

function dirToArray($ftpConnection, $dir) { 

    $result = array(); 

    $cdir = ftp_nlist($ftpConnection, $dir); 
    foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
    { 
        $subs_value = substr($value, strlen($dir) + 1);
        // assuming its a folder if there's no dot in the name 
        if (strpos($value, '.') === false) {
            $result[$subs_value] = dirToArray($ftpConnection, $value);
        }
        else
        {
            $result[] = $subs_value;
        }
    } 
    return $result; 
}
```